# Python - Discord.py - wait_for() unexpected keyword for my Cog

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a unexpected error when i use `wait_for()` in my cog file for my discord bot.

Error say :

> `wait_for()` got an unexpected keyword argument 'check'

How i can solve this problem ?

the code :

````
while tourGrange == True and finGrange == 0:

            tourGrange = False
            avance = 0
            choix = random.choice(situation)

            await ctx.message.delete()

            outilsMecanique = ["Clé à molette", "Clé à tube", "Pinces combinées", "Marteau à griffes", "Tournevis", "clé"]
            outilsAgricole = ["Faux", "Hache", "Binette", "Pelle", "Rateau", "Scie", "Brouette", "clé"]
            avance = 1

            #Vérifie l'auteur de la réaction
            def checkEmojiGrange(reaction, user):
                if avance == 1:
                    return user == ctx.message.author and message.id == reaction.message.id and (str(reaction.emoji) == "" or str(reaction.emoji) == "")
                if avance == 2:
                    return user == ctx.message.author and message.id == reaction.message.id and (str(reaction.emoji) == "✅" or str(reaction.emoji) == "❌")

            #Message de commencement
            await ctx.send(f"""```diff\n+ Aprés être rentrer dans la grange.\n+ {ctx.message.author.name} voit énormément d'outils agricoles, ainsi qu'un vieux tracteur !```""")
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            message = await ctx.send(f"""```diff\n- Souhaitez-vous regardé ces outils agricoles  ou le tracteur  ?```""")

            #choix de la fouille
            await message.add_reaction("")
            await message.add_reaction("")

            #situation en fonction de la reaction
            try:
                reaction, user = await asyncio.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout = 10, check = checkEmojiGrange)

            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                await ctx.send("La fouille à été annulée automatiquement.")
                messages = await ctx.channel.history(limit=0+3).flatten()
                await asyncio.sleep(4)
                for message in messages:
                    await message.delete()
                tourGrange, finGrange = True, 1
                return
````

Answer (score 2):

[`asyncio.wait_for`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait_for) doesn't have check keyword. You have to use [`client.wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for) instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you should use `await client.wait_for()` where `client` is your [`discord.Client`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client) object.

So, in your code, use:

```py
reaction, user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout = 10, check = checkEmojiGrange)
```

instead of:

```py
reaction, user = await asyncio.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout = 10, check = checkEmojiGrange)
```

Answer (score 0):

I create it and now it say:

> wait_for() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'

So i set like this:

```
reaction, user = await client.wait_for(event = "reaction_add", timeout = 10, check = checkEmojiGrange)
```

and now :

> wait_for() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Answer (score 0):

For the 'self' argument i add it like this :

```
reaction, user = await client.wait_for(self, event = "reaction_add", timeout = 10, check = checkEmojiGrange)
```

and now its say :

> 'CogFouiller' object has no attribute 'loop'